Cross Power Spectral Density of Three Signals?
I am performing a method of data analysis that requires estimating the CPSD between two measured signals. I actually have three signals, so I typically sum two of them and cross them with the third. Is there a analogous concept to the traditional cross power spectral density but for three signals at once? Or is there a more appropriate way to estimate the cross power spectrum between three individual signals?

What information are you trying to extract? Do you need some sort of measure of coherence between the three datasets?

I don’t see anything simpler than summing the two. I do the CPSD as the complex conjugate product of the FFTs- so you could sum the time domain waveforms and FFT or if you have the FFTs already you could sum the two complex conjugate products - same result.

The question I'd have here is what you need the three-signal CPSD(-alike) result for; for example, CPSD is the Fourier transform of the cross-correlation function between two signals, and the 3 pair-wise cross-correlation functions can be used to determine the location of an emitter E between three receive antennas A, B and C (and you really need all three cross-correlations, $AB, BC, C*A$, otherwise you will only know that E is somewhere on an infinite curve). So I wonder whether you three-signals problem can really be broken down to fewer than three CPSD estimates!

Didn't have the chance to write out an answer until now, but wanted to at least provide some mathematical explanation for your options.
Let's say you have signals $x_{1}(t),x_{2}(t),x_{3}(t)$. What you are describing is computing the cross PSD between $x_{1}(t)+x_{2}(t)$ and $x_{3}(t)$. Because calculating an autocorrelation function is linear, you are summing the cross PSDs $\phi_{13}(\omega)$ and $\phi_{23}(\omega)$, so you are not getting information about $\phi_{12}(\omega)$. The proof is pretty easy,
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[x_{1}(t)+x_{2}(t)\right]x_{3}^{*}(t-\tau)dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x_{1}(t)x_{3}^{*}(t-\tau)dt + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x_{2}(t)x_{3}^{*}(t-\tau)dt
\end{equation}
To compute this PSD we then have
\begin{align}
\phi(\omega) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[x_{1}(t)+x_{2}(t)\right]x_{3}^{*}(t-\tau)e^{-j\omega t}dt \\ &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x_{1}(t)x_{3}^{*}(t-\tau)e^{-j\omega t}dt + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x_{2}(t)x_{3}^{*}(t-\tau)e^{-j\omega t}dt
\end{align}
To retain information about $\phi_{12}(\omega)$, you would have to compute its cross-PSD separately. Another option is to compute a coherence spectra for each pair, for example,
\begin{equation}
\psi_{12}(\omega) = \frac{\phi_{12}(\omega)}{\sqrt{\phi_{11}(\omega)\phi_{22}(\omega)}}
\end{equation}
which computes a normalized correlation coefficient.
If you are wanting to compute a single transformation encapsulating all three signals, there is something called the bispectral density. This is computed as the 2D-FFT of the third cumulant, defined as
\begin{equation}
\Phi(\omega_{1},\omega_{2}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x_{1}(\tau_{1})x_{2}(\tau_{2})x_{3}^{*}(\tau_{1}+\tau_{2})e^{-j\omega_{1}\tau_{1}}e^{-j\omega_{2}\tau_{2}}d\tau_{1}d\tau_{2}
\end{equation}
Whether or not this would contain the information you are looking for is application dependent. You might only need the two cross-PSDs, or you might need more. My personal recommendation would be to start with the three individual cross-PSDs, though.
